# Toggle Text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've found a a few articles here on this topic but none seem to answer exactly what I'm looking for.

Here is my current code:

```
    $(".email-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this)
    .text("Close")
    .toggleClass("active");
});
```

When I select the word "Email" which has the class "email-slide" the top panel slides down, and the word "Email" turns to white, and the word "Email" turns into the word "Close".

All good so far. But when clicking "Close" though the color and panel go back to normal, the word "Close" does not turn back into the word "Email". Instead of .text("Close") I tried .toggleText("class") but it seems that does not work. Is there something similar I could do it accomplish it by adding the least amount of code possible? Thank you!

UPDATE - I am able to accomplish it by using the following code, but was hoping that would be a more efficient/shorter way of doing it. If not, let me know. Thanks!

```
$(".email-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});

$(".email-slide").toggle(function (){
    $(this).text("Close")
}, function(){
    $(this).text("Email")
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could try:

```
$(".email-slide").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");

    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    if ($(this).text() == "Close")
       $(this).text("Email")
    else
       $(this).text("Close");

});
```

Or instead of comparing the `text()` value, you can also test for `$(this).hasClass("active")`.

H.t.h. :)

Answer (score 26):

You don't have anything that sets the text back to 'Email'. There isn't a toggle method for content. You will have to do a test and set the value accordingly.

```
$(".email-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    var text = $(this).text() == 'Email' ? 'Close' : 'Email';
    $(this)
    .text(text)
    .toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a shorthand for the above answer:

```
$(".email-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this)
   .text( ($(this).text() == 'Close' ? 'Email' : 'Close') )
   .toggleClass("active");
});
```

Adam

Comment: Even this `.text($(this).text() == "Close" ? "Email" : "Close")` works [`http://jsbin.com/mehur/2/`](http://jsbin.com/mehur/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 3):

This is a method to swap text. It is an alternate approach to replacing text.

**HTML**

```
<div class="toggleAbout">
    <h2 class="toggleOff">Click</h2>
    <h2 class="toggleOn">Close</h2> <!-- this will be hidden at first -->
</div>

<div class="about">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.toggleAbout h2.toggleOff { display: block; }
.toggleAbout h2.toggleOn { display: none; } /* this will be hidden at first */
.about { display: none; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.toggleAbout h2').click(function()
{
    $('.about').slideToggle('slow', function()
    {
        $('.toggleAbout h2').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the (this) is screwing it up. You may have to use the class name instead :)

I had the exact same thing the other day, if you see my post: [slideToggle jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293260/slidetoggle-jquery-function)

Answer (score 0):

I think JQuery don't have toggleText feature. You have to manually place the "Email" text there on close event.

$(this).text("Email");

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```
if($('.email-slide').attr('class') == 'inactive')
{
    $('.email-slide').text('Email');
}
else
{
    $('.email-slide').text('Close');
}

$('.email-slide').toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe an easy way would be:

```
if ($(this).text() == 'Email')
   $(this).text("Close");
else
   $(this).text("Email");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question BUT:

```
$(".email-slide").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).text($(this).hasClass('active')?"Email":"C‌​lose")).toggleClass(‌​'active');
});
```