# Getting text toggle with show/hide content to work, not sure where to place

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, accordion, show

I'm wanting to toggle some HTML text so it either changes to "open" or "close" depending on its state (this text is in a SPAN within a H2 title), but I am having difficulty trying to get it to work and finding the right place.
My JS toggle works fine, but how do I get jquery to change HTML text?

This is the JS (no toggle text here as couldn't get it to work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

    $(".open").click(function(){

    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('h2').removeClass('active');

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('.panel').slideUp(300);
    }

    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);

    });
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h2 class="open">test <span>Open</span></h2>
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>lorem ipsum sit dolor</p>
    </div>

    <h2 class="open">test 2 <span>Open</span></h2>
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>lorem ipsum sit dolor</p>
    <div>
</div>
```

I have searched the forums and found some JS for toggling text:

[Toggle Text with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326910/toggle-text-with-jquery)

but cannot seem to get it to work corectly, any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a newbie to jquery having only been a css/html developer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".accordion h2").on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.hasClass('open') ){ //On click check if h2 has class 'open'
      $this.next('.panel').slideUp(300); //if yes close or slideUp
      $this.find('span').html('Close'); //Change span to 'Close'
    } else {
      $this.next('.panel').slideDown(300); //if no open or slideDown
      $this.find('span').html('Open'); //Change span to 'Open'
    }
    $this.toggleClass('open'); //Toggle class
  });
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, should have made my explanation a little clearer but I'm wanting to change the actual HTML text inside the SPAN tag, so from this: <span>Open</span> to this: <span>Close</span>