# Change content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change content when I click a toggle. I've managed to make it change the text when I click the toggle, but when I hit it again it stays the same. I want it to revert it back to initial value so it works like a real toggle.

Javascript:

```
$( ".switch a" ).on("click", function() {
    $(".switch a").removeClass("active"), $(this).addClass("active"),$('.interval').text('yearly');
});
```

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbEmrM

Comment: please show me ur demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: You have typed in `comma`s instead of `semi colon`s. Change them and it should work fine.

Comment: Why are you using commas instead semicolon?

Comment: could be hlpeful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326910/toggle-text-with-jquery

Comment: @Maverick: Actually, the commas work (because of [the comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14)). But it's not a good idea.

Comment: remove the `commas ","`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Oooh! Really? I didn't know that. Let me check it out.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbEmrM here's the Codepen, so I want it to revert back to monthly when I click it again.

Comment: You can add a condition:

$( ".switch a" ).on("click", function() {
$(this).toggle();
    $(".switch a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
if($(this).text() == 'monthly')
    $(this).text('yearly');
else
$(this).text('monthly');

});

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the text "yearly" when the `.switch a` does not have the class `active` and whatever was originally there if it does. If so, you need to store the text and then restore it. (Also: Don't use the comma operator where semicolons make more sense.)

```
$( ".switch a" ).on("click", function() {
    // Grab the elements we care about
    var $this = $(this),
        $interval = $('.interval');

    // Currently have 'active'?
    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        // Yes, remove it, store the current $interval text, and set it to 'yearly'
        $this.removeClass('active');
        $interval.data('original-text', $interval.text()).text('yearly');
    } else {
        // No, put it back and restore the original $interval text
        $this.addClass('active');
        $interval.text($interval.data('original-text'));
    }
});
```