# Show/hide text with simple inline code

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to code a simple click to read more within a paragraph. I am sure this code worked to both show AND hide on click. When I try this now, it shows the hidden text, but will not hide it when I click again?

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById ('review').style.display=document.getElementById

('review').style.display='none' ? 'block':'none';">

<p>Click here to read our review</p>

<div id="review" style="display: none;">Review text goes here.</div>
```

Any ideas about how to achieve this with simple inline code?

Thanks

Comment: if jQuery is an option try  `$('#review').toggle()`

Comment: You are assigning 'none', need a double-equals in your ternary operator to test for 'none'

Comment: Not sure you get me, I'm saying this line: `document.getElementById('review').style.display='none' ? 'block':'none'` is ASSIGNING the value 'none' with the single-equals, which will always be true and set 'block', you need a double- (or triple-) equals there: `document.getElementById('review').style.display=='none' ? 'block':'none'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/muwyu286/. You have used an assign `=` instead of `==` in `('review').style.display='none' ? 'block':'none';"`

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('review').style.display = document.getElementById('review').style.display == 'none' ? 'block':'none';">
    <p>Click here to read our review</p>
    <div id="review" style="display: none;">Review text goes here.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this to learn about toggling through jquery.

[Toggle Text with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326910/toggle-text-with-jquery)